# Does "Chrome custom tab" support VectorDrawable?

Tags: android, google-chrome, chrome-custom-tabs

I work with "chrome custom tab"(cct) and everything runs O.K.

However if I wanna add "actions" to buildIn Toolbar the cct works only with old "png" files under drawable directory. I've switched to work with vector asset to generate vector-drawables and do all thing by using vector-drawable-compat, it seems that the cct doesn't work with it, right?

Thanks for whom can give me an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately Chrome Custom Tab supports only the bitmap format, as explained in the [platform_frameworks_support](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/marshmallow-mr1-release/customtabs/src/android/support/customtabs/CustomTabsIntent.java#L90-L95) repository:

> ```
> /**
>  * Key that specifies the {@link Bitmap} to be used as the image source for the action button.
>  *  The icon should't be more than 24dp in height (No padding needed. The button itself will be
>  *  48dp in height) and have a width/height ratio of less than 2.
>  */
> public static final String KEY_ICON = "android.support.customtabs.customaction.ICON";
> ```